# Access 2013 crashing on splash screen

Tags: windows, ms-access

Hope you can help.  I am running MS Office 2013 on a Windows 8 OS, whenever I try to open Access I get the error "Microsoft Access Has Stopped Working".  This was working fine the last time I used Access which would have been about 2 or 3 weeks ago.  I've went into the Event Log and see the following error:

```
Faulting application name: MSACCESS.EXE, version: 15.0.4535.1001, time stamp:0x51e8ea35
Faulting module name: igd10umd32.dll, version: 9.17.10.2849, time stamp: 0x5044220b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x001fe39e
Faulting process ID: 0x20e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceb3d996a29303
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\MSACCESS.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\
Report ID: d6c26d95-1fcc-11e3-be88-
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Any help I could get on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I've not checked all of the Office packages, but Excel and Word are both working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Alex

Comment: LibreOffice, just use that instead. It'll open and save to all versions of Access.

Comment: Is the problem limited to one specific db file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.  My laptop has Catalyst graphics controller to switch between on board graphics and the high performance graphics, Access had been switch to using the high performance card but there was a conflict between the driver for that card and the dll for Access.  I switched it back to the other card and everything is working fine.

Thanks

Alex